# "align-items: flex-start" aligns children along parent's available space

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to align each child DIRECTLY after one another (vertically). Apparently `align-items: flex-start` doesn't do that completely because there is some auto-spacing between each child.

Below is a snippet of the result I get. The children align themselves along their parent's available space, which is not what I like to achieve. What I want is each child to align directly after its previous sibling (vertically, as in the snippet).

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: `flex-flow: column wrap` and `align-content: flex-start` both did the trick. I forgot, however, to add `align-self: flex-end` to the last child, which doesn't work when either of the two solutions above is applied.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#container > div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
#container > div:nth-child(1) { height: 5%; }
#container > div:nth-child(2) { height: 10%; }
#container > div:nth-child(3) { height: 20%; align-self: flex-end; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You set your divs to width 100%, so of course they are not going to line up one after another in a row. Also, you want rows and `align-items`  is for vertical alignment. `justify-content` is what you need for `flex-start` but that's already the default and does not need to be defined. Read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ it has everything you need

Comment: @Huangism - Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I'll be more specific in the post. I do want to align the divs vertically like it does in the example. Only not with that auto-spacing between each div. `justify-content` is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you definitely was not clear. `flex-flow: row wrap;` you have row instead of column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`align-content: flex-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) on parent element because initial value is `stretch`.

> **stretch**
>
> If the combined size of the items along the cross axis is less than the size of the alignment container, any auto-sized items have their size increased equally (not proportionally), while still respecting the constraints imposed by max-height/max-width (or equivalent functionality), so that the combined size exactly fills the alignment container along the cross axis.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
#container > div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
#container > div:nth-child(1) { height: 5%; }
#container > div:nth-child(2) { height: 10%; }
#container > div:nth-child(3) { height: 20%; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Update: Another solution is to set `flex-direction: column` then you can use `margin` to position specific flex item.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#container > div {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
#container > div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 5%;
}
#container > div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 10%;
}
#container > div:nth-child(3) {
  height: 20%;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same as @Huangism - This also kind of works. However, I cannot set `align-self: flex-end` to the last div which was a step that I didn't include in the question :(

Comment: You don't have defined height on container.

Comment: I do have a defined height via `top` and `bottom` properties. Adding `height: 100%` doesn't do the trick anyways.

Comment: @Nordling Art You are right, i updated my answer with another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set column for the flow

```
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
#container > div:nth-child(3) { height: 20%; margin-top: auto; }
```

Updated:

Add margin top auto to the last child

https://jsfiddle.net/qghsgze5/2/

Comment: That does work. However, now I cannot set `align-self: flex-end` to the last div :(